# tablelayoutpanel won't change background image

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

the image name is loaded from the ini file, and the background is set for the first time without any problems. However, when it loads another image from the ini file based on the action, it will not set a different background.

```
 var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
 IniData data = parser.ReadFile("configuration.ini");

 int panelRow = GetMyClass.toInt(data[config_PanelCount]["rowCount"]);
 int panelColl = GetMyClass.toInt(data[config_PanelCount]["collCount"]);
 string bckGround = data[config_PanelCount]["background"];
 tableStolovi.Controls.Clear();
 tableStolovi.BackgroundImage = null;
            

 string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
 Image bck = Image.FromFile(appPath + "\\" + bckGround);
 tableStolovi.BackgroundImage = bck;
 tableStolovi.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

how to set background every time for tablelayoutpanel

Comment: I do not like tablelayoutpanel because there is a very limited number of properties you can set.  Every time I tried doing a tablelayoutpanel I gave up and instead create a main panel and added my own child panels which look exactly like the layout panel, but do not have issues with not being able to change background image.

Comment: Debug issue.  What is the value of `bck` when you run this piece of code?  If it works when you load it, and not later, then it sounds like the issue is with the ini file.  Ini files are old, use the Settings properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to refresh the tableLayoutPanel after setup a new background.

```
tableStolovi.Refresh();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I found a mistake. the code works perfectly in another place, I got a wrong picture. Excuse me please and thank you again for your effort